# Пустое значение в SharedPreferences Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-shared-preferences, android-webview

Проблема такова: почему у меня запись пустого значения? Код для записи в память рабочий. Проверял.

*ниже часть метода, который работает внутри WebViewClient.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Document html = Jsoup.connect(USER_INFO_URL).maxBodySize(0).get();
                Elements user_info = html.select("strong");

                ArrayList<Element> user_info_list = new ArrayList<>();
                for(Element element : user_info){
                    user_info_list.add(element);
                }

                SharedPreferences sharedGROUP = getSharedPreferences("INFO", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editorGROUP = sharedGROUP.edit();
                editorGROUP.putString("USER_INFO_GROUP", user_info_list.get(3).text());
                editorGROUP.apply();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
```

Ниже скриншот с информацией, часть которой я хочу сохранить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможно несколько вариантов:  не срабатывает `try{`, `text()` возвращает "", вы неправильно считываете значение из SP(например, ключ разный) . Посмотрите где-то там.

Answer (score 1):

возможно это случилось из-за асинхронной записи `apply()`, попробуйте использовать вместо него синхронный `commit()`

```
SharedPreferences sharedGROUP = getSharedPreferences("INFO", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editorGROUP = sharedGROUP.edit();
editorGROUP.putString("USER_INFO_GROUP", user_info_list.get(3).text());
editorGROUP.commit();
```

Comment: @Jarvis_J вы уверены?! Автор по-моему предложил абсолютно нормальное решение...

Comment: @Barmaley, нет, не уверен.

Comment: @Jarvis_J технически это может и не так (с точки зрения программирования), но как модератор вы совершили ошибку - призываю исправить свою же собственную ошибку.

Comment: @Barmaley, не думаю, что я совершил ошибку, это только ваше мнение. И по-прежнему считаю, что предложенный вариант не является ответом на вопрос. Но мне лень начинать бессмысленный спор. Тем более, что комментарии не для этого.

Comment: @Barmaley, мы в модераторском чатике запутались) Можете пояснить суть проблемы с ответом?

Comment: Прощу прощения. Я нашёл ошибку в коде) Это был мой провтык, т.к. парсинг проходил одновременно с выводом на экран... Я не успел взять данные, как сразу же выводил их. Прошу прощения ещё раз - мало опыта и знаний, учу java на досуге:) А SP рабочий)